# Perl how do I add text to specifically second line of file?

Tags: perl

Trying to do this sort of thing in perl:

```
sed '1 a<!-- $Header: $\n Purpose: system generated file -->' -i test.xml
```

Add the header block and purpose to line #2 in the file for xml, shell scripts, etc...

Don't want to do this either:

```
`sed '1 a<!-- \$Header: \$\n Purpose: system generated file -->' -i test.xml`
```

But realize it's an option if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 3):

If you only pass one file, you can use the following:

```
perl -i -pe'
   $_ .= "<!-- \$Header: \$\n Purpose: system generated file -->\n" if $. == 1;
' test.xml
```

If you might pass multiple files, you'll need to add a line so that [`$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) is reset at the end of each file.

```
perl -i -pe'
   $_ .= "<!-- \$Header: \$\n Purpose: system generated file -->\n" if $. == 1;
   close(ARGV) if eof;
' test*.xml
```

(Note: `eof()` means something different than just `eof`. how awful is that!)

I added line breaks for readability. The commands will work as is, but you can remove the line breaks if you so desire.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
perl -ple '++$i == 2 and $_ = "changed" # change $_ as you want' in.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: The title says "add text to". I guess `$_ = "inserted before\n$_"` will work anyway.

Comment: If it's guaranteed there will be two lines (likely), yeah.